# Azure Dynamic App Service instance that starts up and shuts down automatically based on the current needs

Tags: azure, google-app-engine, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Microsoft Azure / Google Cloud and I am currently comparing these two different cloud solution providers, before starting a new project. I am planning to write a web application using either [Google Cloud App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) or [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/).

I want to start with a very basic service instance, which I want to call via HTTPS. To reduce charges it would be nice to only pay for used service minutes resp. that the instance only runs, when needed.

[Google Cloud offers dynamic instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#introduction_to_instances), where compute instances are shutdown, when idle and started for incoming requests. Which seems way cheaper for a seldom used prototype and first usage of cloud services.

> Instances are resident or dynamic. A dynamic instance starts up and shuts down automatically based on the current needs. [...] When an application is not being used at all, App Engine turns off its associated dynamic instances, but readily reloads them as soon as they are needed.

Unfortunately, I found in the Azure documentation only an [Overview of autoscale in Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines, Cloud Services, and Web Apps](http://Overview%20of%20autoscale%20in%20Microsoft%20Azure%20Virtual%20Machines,%20Cloud%20Services,%20and%20Web%20Apps), which does not cover my question of an automatic instance shutdown in idle state. Also [Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management) does not satisfy my information need, because I am looking only for a compute instance and not a full VM.

Is there an equivalent in the Azure domain, that allows to automatically start up and shut down app service instances, based on the usage resp. incoming requests?

Depending on the functionality of the two cloud service provider, I am deciding which one to use. Has anybody experience with this matter in the Azure domain? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with Azure App Service alone as of now (24-Feb-2019). But you could combine an Azure function to fire up a App Service instance and then forward all incoming traffic to an app hosted in this App Service via an Azure function proxy, [see this description on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api). I was planning to try this for while now too. In theory it should work... From experience, App Service instances fire up quickly, so the warm up time should be acceptable. Even better, you could keep free or shared App Service plan instance with your app running and forward the Azure function calls to it by default. On increasing load, move the app to a pre-configured plan which supports auto scaling.

Of course you could try to implement the entire app via a set of Azure functions which are fully "dynamic" using your terminology. Depending on the architecture of your application, this might actually be the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

The Autoscale feature of Azure offers you to scale out/scale in based on configurable criterias, take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started). You are limited by your pricing [tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits). Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-environment-auto-scale) example will help you get an insight.

Comment: That’s not directly that what I am asking for. I want to know if it is possible to automatically shut down an instance, if there is no traffic and that it starts again, when needed.

Comment: I misinterpret your question. Once you start an App Service you also pay for it, even if unloaded in unused state (take a look at the Always On option). What you could do is create an Action Group based on Metrics and start or stop resources with a runbook. I have't tried it myself yet, but will do this once i find time this week, and keep you posted.